# Astro with React. AVIF Images not rendering on mobile

Tags: reactjs, image, astrojs, avif

Using astro and react I have a custom image component:

```
         <ImageWBorder
              src="images/pix.avif"
              alt="main band image"
              leftBorder
            />
```

**ImageWBorder**

```
  return (
    <div className="aspect-square relative z-10 h-64 sm:h-72 sm:h-80 mobile:h-96 xl:h-100">
      <img
        alt={alt}
        src={src}
        className="object-cover w-full h-full rounded-full"
      />
      <div style={{ zIndex: -1 }} className={styles} />
    </div>
  )
```

Images render fine on desktop but on my mobile device no image with the .avif extension renders. I thought .avif was widely supported on all browsers and operating systems? I am testing on an iPhone 13 on both Safari and Chrome.Does anyone else have any experience with these issues and can recommend a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While AVIF has increasingly good support, it still is not universal. [Can I Use reports around 20% of users won’t be able to render AVIF images currently.](https://caniuse.com/avif) Only Safari 16 on iOS appears to support AVIF and Safari Desktop does not yet support it. Because all browsers on iOS use Safari’s engine under-the-hood (including Chrome), they also won’t be able to support AVIF on older versions of iOS.

The solution currently is to either pick a more widely supported image format, e.g. WebP or JPEG, or to use responsive image techniques with the `<picture>` element to offer multiple formats. This allows browsers that don’t support AVIF to fall back to another format. For example:

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="image.avif" type="image/avif">
  <source srcset="image.webp" type="image/webp">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="A description of the image." 
    width="300" height="200" loading="lazy" decoding="async">
</picture>
```